# Navbar collapse not expanding with dropdown after clicking on it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I have just started using Bootstrap 3, and I want my header to be fixed at the top, content in it vertically aligned with the content in body, and lastly, responsive.

Everything works fine except that clicking on collapsed navbar doesn't seem to work. Clicking on those small icon with three bars one over other doesn't show me my list below.

I know this could be a very basic mistake but clicking on this kid right here, doesn't work:

[image: collapsed navbar]

I think I might be doing something wrong with classes in my header.

This is my code:

```
<header class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
<div class="col-10">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Text</a>
  </div>

  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="home_button"> <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> </a> </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#" > My Account </a> </li><br>
          <li> <a href="#"> Logout </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

The only thing I have in my custom css is:

```
@media (min-width: 980px){
    body{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
}
```

but I don't think that would be causing this problem.

The things I have included before my header in my html are:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-3.0.0-min.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap-3.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="/static/app/bssgame2/css/my_custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

which are all in my local directory.

Searching for "collapse not working"/"collapse click not working" shows me bunch of results which seem to be related to the problem of this icon itself not showing up.

Including collapse.js that came with bootstrap didn't fix this problem either.

Comment: your button defines `data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"` but you have not add this class to your nav. Use  `<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" role="navigation">` and your code will work fine

Comment: Wow... thanks! To be honest, I have been using bootstrap without knowing what these data-toggles and stuff like that actually do. 

Please add your comment as an answer, I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Collapsing of the navbar uses the collapse plugin, see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse. So add data-toggle="collapse" and a data-target to your navbar button. And add the same class as used for data-target to the nav element of your navbar:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

and:

```
  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
```

More about [Migrating](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/) from Bootstrap v3 to Bootstrap v4 [here in docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/).

Comment: Typo. ``data-target="navbar-collapse"`` should be ``data-target=".navbar-collapse"``.

Comment: Typo. `class="navbar-toggle"` should be `class="navbar-toggler"`.

Answer (score 1):

For others who will get here from a web search:

I had this same problem - not being able to expand a navbar - but all of my code was fine. If you've checked your `data-toggle` per [@Bass Jobsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976460/navbar-collapse-not-expanding-with-dropdown-after-clicking-on-it#answer-19013727)'s answer, and are still having issues then [check your CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154836/collapsed-nav-button-not-expanding-in-bootstrap/48954764#48954764).

#### My problem was that I had a *network-level ad blocker* that was blocking some of my CDN'ed scripts.

Facepalm.